# Probsvm model using for multiclass

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a multi-class svm model using probsvm package and I got this error:

```
Error in probsvm(tra[, -72], y, type = "ovo", Inum = 10, fold = 10, lambdas = 2^seq(-10,  : 
  The dimensions of x and y do not match.



library(kernlab)
    library(probsvm)
    s <-sample(213,149) #random sample
    #split data
    tra <- data[s,]
    x <- tra[,-72]
    y <-tra$Cardio
    tes<- data[-s,]
    X <- subset(tes, select = -Cardio)
    y <- tes$Cardio
    # train one-against-all models
    svm.model= probsvm(tra[,-72],y,type="ovo",Inum=10,fold=10,lambdas=2^seq(-10,10,by=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code you have `y <- tes$Cardio` which is replacing   `y <-tra$Cardio`. Does that solves your problem ?

```
In the function there is a test
    x.train = x
    y.train = as.vector(y)
   if (nrow(x.train) != length(y.train)) {
        stop("The dimensions of x and y do not match.")
```

what do you have for `length(y)` and `nrow(tra[,-72])` ?

Comment: Sorry for confusing y but i puted it in comment so the problem remains till now  Error in x.train.neg[index.neg.train, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: what do you have for dim(tra[,-72]) and dim(tes$Cardio) ?

Comment: dim(tra) 149  71, dim(y)NULL because is a vector of tra of 149 observations

Comment: What do you have in str(tes$Cardio) ?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your dataset ? dput(tra)

Comment: length(y) nrow(tra)
[1] 149
[1] 149

Comment: nrow of tra is equal to length of y in my case. I cheked them

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what the problem is, without the data I can't test it.